# Построчный поиск в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Как реализовать построчный поиск в файле на Delphi? если можно с примером.

Comment: ну сперва, вам нужно понять что ищете, можете это обработать регулярками. затем вам нужно счить весь файл в буфер. в этом буфере вы и будите искать. далее вам нужно определиться с алгаритмом поиска. как определитесь с аогоритмом, реалезуйте его и сосбственно все.

Comment: Наверное дельфи умеет читать файл построчно. Тогда читаете строку, ищете в ней. Учитывая написанное выше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var
  LF: TextFile;
  LStr: string;
begin
  AssignFile(LF, 'myfile.txt'); // Открываем файл
  Reset(LF);
  try
    while not Eof(LF) do // Пока в файле не кончатся строки, повторяем
    begin
      Readln(LF, LStr); // Читаем следующую строку из файла

      if (LStr = 'abc') // <<-- Условие полного совпадения строки
      or (Pos('x', LStr) > 0) then // <<-- Условия наличия символа в строке
        ShowMessage('Found');
    end;
  finally
    CloseFile(LF); // Закрываем файл
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Нет, только не AssignFile! :) Что вы будете делать с файлами, которые не в ANSI-кодировке?

Comment: @kami Вы не поверите - укажу третий параметр `function AssignFile(var F: File; FileName: String; [CodePage: Word]): Integer;`

Comment: Класс! Плюсанул. Жаль только, что этот третий параметр появился уже в XE-версиях... Понимает почти всё, включая UTF-8 с BOM и без. Но не захотел работать с UTF-16BE... Надо переосмыслить свое отношение к этому наследию турбопаскаля :)

Comment: Тут проблема в том, что построчное чтение файла очень тормозное. Для лабы сойдет - для профессионального софта не выдержит конкуренции. Строки можно преобразовать и сравнить, но таким образом если перечитать файл метров 50, это займет достаточно продолжительное время.  У Readln конечно есть буфер (не по 30-40 байт читается, несколько килобайт), но вот он все равно маленький. Лучше зачитывать поток порциями и в нем уже искать.